# Invalid datetime Cast when WHERE added in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-execution-plan

I have a column of character datetime values, some not valid dates, that I can select without error with:

```
SELECT CAST(cDatetime as datetime)
FROM table 
WHERE cDatetime like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/%'
```

However, if I add a WHERE clause to the above I receive a conversion failed error with:

```
SELECT CAST(cDatetime as datetime)
FROM table 
WHERE cDatetime like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/%'
      and CAST(cDatetime as datetime)>='2015-01-01'
```

Or this:

```
SELECT tDatetime
FROM (SELECT CAST(cDatetime as datetime) tDatetime
       FROM table 
       WHERE cDatetime like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/%') validdates
WHERE tDatetime>='2015-01-01'
```

The estimated execution plan has an index seek with a Predicate of:

```
CAST(cDatetime as datetime)>'2015-01-01' 
AND cDatetime like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/%'
```

which seems to explain the error.  How can I force the execution plan to process the subquery first?  My backup plan is to create a function to handle the date conversion, which would be excluded from optimization.  Is there a better way?

Comment: No way to force the subquery first that I am aware of.

Comment: @Frisbee it can be forced using a cte but as a subquery you are right.

Comment: @SeanLange CTE is just syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISDATE` in following:

```
SELECT CAST(cDatetime as datetime)
FROM table 
WHERE ISDATE(cDatetime) = 1
      and CAST(cDatetime as datetime) >= '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the ISDATE will happen first. You can't short circuit like that in a where clause.

Comment: @SeanLange And in your answer there is no guarantee the derived table will happen first.

Answer (score 0):

Is cDatetime a string ?
Dates are string in form: '12/31/2015' ?

Bad code, but .... It must works.

```
SELECT CAST(cDatetime as datetime)
FROM table 
WHERE cDatetime like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/1%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/200%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/2010%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/2011%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/2012%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/2013%'
      and cDatetime not like '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/2014%'
```